# Unity C# Problems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error:

> An object reference is required to access non-static member
>   `Inventory.ItemID'

I want to change `ItemID` in `Inventory` to 1.

The class `ItemSwordUneq`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ItemSwordUneq : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public bool canPickup = false;

    void Update () 
    {
        if(canPickup == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            GameObject player = GameObject.Find("Player");
            Inventory inventory = player.GetComponent<Inventory>();
            Inventory.ItemID = 1;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        canPickup = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        canPickup = false;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if(canPickup == true)
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(250, 250, 300, 20), "Press 'F' To Pick Up Sword");
        }
    }
}
```

The class `Inventory`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public bool hasItem = false;
    public int ItemID;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Inventory= Method Funtion
and if you want to pass the same for object use inventory.
The link can be of more help!
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/48767-Unity-Tutorials-Inventory

Comment: Cleaned up some code to make this all better readable. For the next time, try to keep relevant code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to write `inventory.ItemID = 1;` instead of `Inventory.ItemID = 1;`.

That is if you want to set the ItemId of the result of `player.GetComponent<Inventory>();` to 1.

You are trying to call a method on the class `Inventory` and not on the object `inventory`, and that does not give any sense if the method is not static.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was so simple... Thanks